# [SOLVED]How to select dual return mode for velodyne VLP16

Tags: ros, velodyne-driver, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

In the velodyne package, how do you select **dual returns mode** for velodyne VLP16?.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212653/%5Bsolved%5Dhow-to-select-dual-return-mode-for-velodyne-vlp16/) by [Tohoku](https://answers.ros.org/users/23006/tohoku/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-07-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-07-01**:
I don't think I've seen support for this added to the velodyne driver, and I haven't even seen any documentation from Velodyne about how to enable it. You may have to add this support yourself.

**Comment by [Tohoku](https://answers.ros.org/users/23006/tohoku/) on 2015-07-01**:
I think dual return was defined here? is it true?
Dual return have been defined in rawdata.h --->    http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/velodyne_pointcloud
program line
00063   static const int VLP16_FIRINGS_PER_BLOCK = 2;  // dual return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After connecting to VLP16, connect to the web server at http://192.168.1.201/ and you will find settings to change many hardware settings. There you can change the return mode.

more details: http://velodynelidar.com/lidar/hdldownloads/63-9114%20rev%20A%20HDL32E%20HDL-32E%20Software%20Version%20V2.0%20Manual.pdf

cheers

---

Originally posted by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) with karma: 387 on 2015-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tohoku](https://answers.ros.org/users/23006/tohoku/) on 2015-07-01**:
Thank you
that solved the my question =)

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-07-02**:
Please click the check mark next to this answer to mark it as solved.